# Asp.NET MVC 3 project templates not showing up

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, async-ctp

I installed the Async CTP w/o knowing it would cause problems with Asp.NET MVC 3.
So I've followed every possible uninstall instruction out there re-installed both SP1 and MVC 3.

However, the MVC 3 templates does not show up in the new project dialogs.
*And I have ensured that target platform is .NET 4 in the dialog, so that is not the cause.*

Any ideas on how to make the MVC 3 templates re-appear?

Comment: Upvoted for the line "And I have ensured that target platform is .NET 4". I haven't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

Clear out the template cache located at "[ProgramFile x86]\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache"

and then run devenv.exe /installvstemplates from the visual studio command line.

Comment: This trick also works for VS2012 (obviously you need to change the path from 10 to 11)

Comment: I am having the same problem, cleared cache but it is of no use. When I write the command it gives me the error "The requested operation requires elevation".

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 then the solution might be here:
http://tedgustaf.com/en/blog/2011/4/installing-asp-net-mvc3-on-visual-studio-2010-sp1/